# simplifying complex fractions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression

${2 \over x^2 - 4}$ + ${1 \over x + 2}$

So I would take the LCM to ${x^2 - 4}$ or using the difference of 2 squares to be ${(x + 2)(x - 2)}$

So I would simplify this to:

${2 + (x - 2) \over (x - 2)(x + 2)}$ which would simplify further to
${2\over x + 2}$

But the answer to the question is ${x \over x^2 - 4}$

I'm not sure how the real answer is achieved and how I am wrong

Comment: The 2x in the second line should be 2? Also, $2+(x-2)=x$

Comment: It should be $\frac{2x + x-2}{x^2-4} = \frac{3x-2}{x^2-4}$.

Comment: you have an extra $x$ on your first expression. As for your question $2+x-2 = x$.

Comment: Sorry, I had ${2x \over x^2 - 4}$ when it should be ${2 \over x^2 - 4}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\frac{2}{x^2-4}+\frac{1}{x+2}$$ $\color{red}{\text{apply} \ a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)}$ $$=\frac{2}{(x-2)(x+2)}+\frac{1}{x+2}$$ $\color{red}{\text{take L.C.M of denominators }}$  $$=\frac{2+x-2}{(x-2)(x+2)}$$$$ =\frac{x}{(x-2)(x+2)}$$ Thus we have following simplified form  $$\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\frac{2}{x^2-4}+\frac{1}{x+2}=\frac{x}{(x-2)(x+2)}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe either answer is correct (although in the case you forgot to subtract the 2 from the other 2 to achieve just $x$ in the numerator).

You would indeed multiply the numerator and denominator top by $(x-2)$, but the result should be different.

$$ \frac{2x}{x^2-4} + \frac{x-2}{x^2-4} = \frac{3x-2}{x^2-4}$$

Which does not simplify further.

**EDIT**: Going off Chinny's (correct) thought that you intended $\frac{2}{x^2-4} + \frac{1}{x+2}$ your error is then in thinking you could cancel out factors in $\frac{2+(x-2)}{(x+2)(x-2)}$, which you cannot. That would only work with a numerator involving multiplication or division (consider the fact that if you really were to manually divide the numerator and denominator by $(x-2)$ you'd get the cancelation, but still have to deal with the $\frac{2}{(x-2)}$ part. (Note that you could still push this through, you'd have $$\frac{\frac{2}{x-2}+1}{x+2} \implies \frac{\frac{2+(x-2)}{x-2}}{x+2} \implies \frac{x}{(x+2)(x-2)}.)$$

Comment: Very correct with how the question is. whilst possible the question is correct. I think the probability of the OP adding an $x$ to the first term on the second line of his post is higher.

Comment: Ah yes, good thought, although I'd love to have an example of textbook being wrong, they are so lofty in their perfection.

Comment: Very true books are known to be wrong! Also I can not figure how the wrong answer came about i.e the cancellation?

Comment: Sorry, I had ${2x \over x^2 - 4}$ when it should be ${2 \over x^2 - 4}$.

Comment: I think it just comes the cancel instinct one might have in early Algebra, I can remember making similar errors not long ago.

Comment: I remember those days as well my friend! +1

Comment: Yes, and they were recent for some of us good sir; I'm still working up to that PhD!

Comment: Mistakes are part and parcel of the phd (I know first hand). If you don't make mistakes you are playing it too safe..all the best with the Phd (no doubt we will cross paths on this site again :) )

Comment: So I've been told many a time. And I look forward to doing so.